# RADIUS calculate Message-Authenticator field (python)

Tags: python, radius

The [documentation](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2869.txt) specifying the Message-Authenticator field is confusing:

```
5.14.  Message-Authenticator

  Earlier drafts of this memo used "Signature" as the name of this
  attribute, but Message-Authenticator is more precise.

String

  When present in an Access-Request packet, Message-Authenticator is
  an HMAC-MD5 [9] checksum of the entire Access-Request packet,
  including Type, ID, Length and authenticator, using the shared
  secret as the key, as follows.

  Message-Authenticator = HMAC-MD5 (Type, Identifier, Length,
  Request Authenticator, Attributes)

  When the checksum is calculated the signature string should be
  considered to be sixteen octets of zero.

  For Access-Challenge, Access-Accept, and Access-Reject packets,
  the Message-Authenticator is calculated as follows, using the
  Request-Authenticator from the Access-Request this packet is in
  reply to:

  Message-Authenticator = HMAC-MD5 (Type, Identifier, Length,
  Request Authenticator, Attributes)

  When the checksum is calculated the signature string should be
  considered to be sixteen octets of zero.  The shared secret is
  used as the key for the HMAC-MD5 hash.  The is calculated and
  inserted in the packet before the Response Authenticator is
  calculated.
```

Quote:

```
  in an Access-Request packet, Message-Authenticator is
  an HMAC-MD5 [9] checksum of the entire Access-Request packet,
  including Type, ID, Length and authenticator, using the shared
  secret as the key, as follows.

  Message-Authenticator = HMAC-MD5 (Type, Identifier, Length,
  Request Authenticator, Attributes)
```

The Message-Authenticator can not obviously be an attribute at this time because it's not been calculated yet.

```
  When the checksum is calculated the signature string should be
  considered to be sixteen octets of zero.
```

What is it referring to when it says "signature"? Is this saying to add the Message-Authenticator in the attributes and set it's value to 16 zeros to calculate the Message-Authenticator and then replace the value???

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but in case it helps anyone else out.  To answer your question, yes you are correct.  This is for Python 2 only.

1. set the default Message-Authenticator as 16-bytes zero
   `req["Message-Authenticator"] = 16*six.b("\x00")`
2. get the raw packet binary
   `raw_packet = req.RequestPacket()`
3. calculate the hmac-md5 with shared secret
   `digest = hmac.new(secret, raw_packet, hashlib.md5)`
4. write back the Message-Authenticator
   `req["Message-Authenticator"] = digest.hexdigest().decode('hex')`